# Jquery-Mobile: How to add the data dynamically to the select menu based on the text box value

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile. In my UI, one text box and one select menu are there. Initially select menu is empty.If the textbox value is more than 1 then some data is added to the select menu otherwise select menu is empty. For this, i am calling the function at the onchange of select menu but it is not working. Please can anybody help me.

Edit:

Ex:

```
$('#Goal_Time').bind( "focus", function(event, ui) 
{   
    if(Goal_WeightVar.val() > 0)
    {
        Goal_WtVar = Math.abs(weightVar.val() - Goal_WeightVar.val());
        Min_DurationVar = Math.round(Goal_WtVar * 2.2);
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            $('#Goal_Time').append('<option value=Min_DurationVar>Min_DurationVar</option>');
        }       
    } 
});
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well Kinda working example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/v5DC3/5/

JS

```
$('#Goal_WeightVar').live('change', function() {
    var weightVar     = 0; // for testing only
    var goalWeightVar = $('#Goal_WeightVar').val();

    if(goalWeightVar > 0)
    {
        Goal_WtVar = Math.abs(weightVar - goalWeightVar);
        Min_DurationVar = Math.round(Goal_WtVar * 2.2);
        for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            $('#Goal_Time').append('<option value='+Min_DurationVar+'>'+Min_DurationVar+'</option>');
        }      
        $('#Goal_Time').listview('refresh'); 
    } 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="Goal_Time_Page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="Goal_WeightVar">Goal Weight:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Goal_WeightVar" id="Goal_WeightVar" value="" />
        <label for="Goal_Time" class="select">Goal Time:</label>
        <select name="Goal_Time" id="Goal_Time">
            <!-- Add options here -->
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will need to tweak it

Comment: thanks it's working. But i want to delete the previous data and add the new data when the value is changed. How to do it

Comment: in the text box or the options?

Answer (score 2):

As it says in the docs of jQuery Mobile, you have to tell the select menu to update it's contents by calling `$('select').selectmenu();`

If it still doesn't work you'll have to post a little sample code so I can have a look at it.

**Edit**:

Actually, that's not even necessary. If you have an empty `<select id="to-append"></select>`, you can just add options via `$('#to-append').append('<option value="a">A</option>')`!

The `onchange` event of the select is probably not the right event to do this though. The select will not change as long as it's empty, thus your event will never get triggered. Try the `blur` event of the text box.

[jQuery Mobile Docs - Select](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/selects/)

Comment: Which method i have to use? onchange() or anything else

Comment: How to append the variable which holds the number to the select menu?because i am adding variable name it displays same variable not the value it holds. I edited the Question plz refer it

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply earlier, I just saw this comment now. If you use `append` like in the example above, you can supply an HTML string that holds the value and the text of the new option.